# R paste input in a way that each row a string is

Tags: r, preprocessor

I have an Excel with data, like this (but then N=1.000):

```
p_evar7_CO.main.
p_evar7_CP.acquistion..sign_up.start
p_evar7_CP.main.
p_evar7_CP.main.facial_stylers00
```

I want to put it in a vector, but with simple copy/pasting it goes wrong. I want this as result:

```
Excel <- c("p_evar7_CO.", "p_evar7_CP.acquistion..sign_up.start", "p_evar7_CP.main.","p_evar7_CP.main.facial_stylers00")
```

So basically: How can I paste a big data file into R, and automatically separate it with a **Comma** and **Quote** each row?

**EDIT** I don't want to load in an Excel data file, but only pasting columns names (and have them as a vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could do a simple `scan()`.

```
scan(file, what = "")
```

where `file` is your file name as a character string.  If you are working with copied text, then you can enter `"clipboard"` as the file name.

```
scan("clipboard", what = "")
```

For example, I copied the file text from your question for the following code.

```
scan("clipboard", what="")
# Read 4 items
# [1] "p_evar7_CO.main."                     "p_evar7_CP.acquistion..sign_up.start"
# [3] "p_evar7_CP.main."                     "p_evar7_CP.main.facial_stylers00"
```

Comment: Amazing function! Do you know in addition how I can save it as vector (for the next R sessions?). 

I tried: 
X <- scan("clipboard", what = "")

And the results are in X now. But the next session (if my clipboard is empty) the vector is gone (I guess).

I tried to copy all the files after "print" them, but then I have to take care with the: 
[1], [2], [3] etc. (while I only want to have the different strings)

Comment: Sure, you can use `save()`.  Or do `q("yes")` when you quit R.  This will save all your session objects for later use.